# Setting up a disk-less workstation environment via pxeboot

Tags: linux, fedora

I have PXEBOOT working just fine, but the OS itself isn't booting properly. What's the proper fstab entries? I google and there are many variations and I've tried them all. My image came from a new Fedora 15 install. I've tried using the fstab below as well as removing everything out of it.

My tftpboot parameter ...

```
append initrd=/images/fedora/dracut.img nousb root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=NFS_SERVER:/admin/linux/fedora/root
```

NFS Mount ...

```
/admin/linux/fedora/root *(rw,no_root_squash,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

Client's fstab ...

```
none   /proc   proc    defaults    0 0
/dev/nfs   /   nfs defaults    0 0
none   /dev/pts    devpts  defaults    0 0
none   /tmp    tmpfs   defaults    0 0
none   /var/run    tmpfs   defaults    0 0
none   /var/lock   tmpfs   defaults    0 0
none   /var/tmp    tmpfs   defaults    0 0
```

Comment: Can you verify that the NFS mount is mountable from an anonymous user from the PXEBOOT system?  Maybe post relevant parts from your NFS `exports` file.

Comment: `/admin/linux/fedora/root *(rw,no_root_squash,sync,no_subtree_check)` and i would post error messages but there are too many. I can tell you it mainly has to do with the system not being able to mount /. Here's one...`Starting sm-client: can not chdir(/var/spool/clientmqueue/): Permission denied.

Comment: It looks like you are missing `rw` in your tftp kernel parameters.  That might explain the permission denied error on starting sendmail.  You can try adding just before `nfsroot`.

Comment: I believe I've tried that. ANy idea as to what the client's fstab should look like?

Comment: Getting "mount: only root can do that (effective UID is 505).